# Deleting everything from a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro right now which adds stuff to a worksheet (text, formatting, pictures), then it prints the worksheet at my default printer, and then clears the worksheet.

This is the code I have right now where `i` is the number of times it enters data and `25` is the number of rows affected each time it adds data.

```
Range("A1", "I" & i * 25).Clear
```

My problem is that it clears the text, it unmerges cells and it removes all formatting but it does not delete the pictures.  What do I need to do differently to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim s as Shape
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    s.Delete
next
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove pictures:

```
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    s.Delete
Next s
```

Comment: @Floris..the **For** loop appears to work............from the post's title, I assume all shapes should be deleted

Answer (score 2):

You could try simply:

```
with Activesheet
   .UsedRange.Clear
   .DrawingObjects.Delete
End With
```

You can also use:

```
.Pictures.Delete
```

in place of

```
   .DrawingObjects.Delete
```

if it's only pictures you need to remove.

Comment: I just tried that `.Pictures.Delete` and it's repetedly giving me a `424: object required` error, and it won't let me kill the program...

Comment: It would replace the `.DrawingObjects.Delete` line in my code - it has to be inside the `With...End With` block I posted, or use `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete`